# Algebra Relacional - Consulta em 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde,Estou com uma dificuldade em conseguir retornar um valor do meu banco quando ele tem dois atributos, eu estou partindo deste enunciado.

> Selecione os nomes das peças que usam os materias com nomes “Tampo
>   Redondo 1m” e “Parafuso 3cm”, (não pode aparecer a peça que usa apenas
>   um deles).

Tenho essa estrutura de tabelas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei imaginar ua consulta sql para poder passar para a Algebra Relacional sendo essa consulta:

```
  Select * from material_peca AS MP join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop JOIN material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 
where M.nomem = "Tampo Redondo 1m" or M.nomem = "Parafuso 3cm";
```

Porem assim ele retorna todos sem excessão, porém necessito que ele retorne apenas quando houver os dois jeitos, ai tentei com um select dentro do select:

```
Select * from material_peca AS MP join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop JOIN material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 

where M.nomem = "Tampo Redondo 1m" and (select M.nomem from M where M.nomem = "Parafuso 3cm");
```

Este é um exercicio para poder entender mais sobre Algebra porém nao consigo compreender nem se quer o banco, se alguem puder me ajudar... fiz essa parte em algebra porém não sei se está correta:

> π nomep ((σ nomem = Tampo Redondo 1m (material_peca |x| material)) ^
>   (σ nomem = Parafuso (material_peca |x| material)))

Comment: Em seu comando não existe nenhuma referência a peça com nomep “Prateleira Média de Madeira” como pede o exercício. Você não informou o significado de "quando houver os dois jeitos". Em seu segundo comando SQL não tem sentido este AND (sub-select). Seria bom você postar a estrutura de suas tabelas.

Comment: Você quer retornar o nomem, quando nomep for "Prateleira Média de Madeira" isso?

Comment: Gostaria de retornar o nomep quando o nomem for "Tampo Redondo 1m" e "Parafuso 3cm"

Comment: Verifica se algo do tipo da certo: :Select * from material_peca AS MP inner join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop inner JOIN material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 
and (M.nomem = "Tampo Redondo 1m" or M.nomem = "Parafuso 3cm")

Comment: Visto seu comentario acima "Gostaria de retornar o nomep quando o nomem for "Tampo Redondo 1m" e "Parafuso 3cm" ", nao consigo ver qual a relaçao dele com o enunciado "Selecione os nomes dos materiais usados na fabricação da peça com nomep “Prateleira Média de Madeira” ". sao duas coisas diferentes

Comment: Não tem sentido a frase "Gostaria de retornar o nomep quando o nomem for "Tampo Redondo 1m" e "Parafuso 3cm"". Um campo não pode conter simultaneamente 2 valores (exceto para eventuais atributos multivalorados, o que não é o caso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operador UNION deve resolver, abaixo a query:

```
Select * from material_peca AS MP 
inner join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop 
inner join material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 
WHERE (M.nomem = "Tampo Redondo 1m")
UNION
Select * from material_peca AS MP 
inner join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop 
inner join material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 
WHERE (M.nomem = "Parafuso 3cm")
```

Dessa forma ele irá trazer os resultados que estão nas 2 consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Levando em considereçao o comentario: Gostaria de retornar o nomep quando o nomem for "Tampo Redondo 1m" e "Parafuso 3cm", acredito que você possa tentar algo do tipo:

```
Select * from material_peca AS MP inner join peca AS P on P.codigop = MP.codigop 
                                  inner JOIN material AS M on MP.codigom = M.codigom 
                                  and (M.nomem = "Tampo Redondo 1m" or M.nomem ="Parafuso 3cm")
```

Comment: Em sql sim porem eu preciso tambem da Algebra Relacional, conseguiria me explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de ter estudado Álgebra Relacional a um bom tempo, creio que a expressão possa ser traduzida para SQL como:

```
SELECT P.nomep from material_peca AS MP JOIN peca AS P ON P.codigop = MP.codigop
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM material AS M WHERE M.codigom = MP.codigom AND M.nomem = 'Tampo Redondo 1m')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM material AS M WHERE M.codigom = MP.codigom AND M.nomem = 'Parafuso 3cm');
```

Será que o que deseja não é a intersecção?

```
π nomep ((σ nomem = Tampo Redondo 1m (material_peca |x| material)) ⋂ (σ nomem = Parafuso (material_peca |x| material)))
```